# liferay sub domains are not redirecting some times

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 I have created multiple portal instances(Subdomains)  using database sharding.

It was working properly, from past few days redirection is not working properly after using the system for a day or two days randomly one of the subdomains shows following  proxy redirect error without any error log in server

**Proxy Error**

**The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.**

**The proxy server could not handle the request  GET /web/guest/welcome.**

it needs server restart and all subdomains work properly again after restarting server this is happening repeatedly from past 2 weeks.

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I have used Liferay shards for creating portal instances'

recently I changed server mode to https.

If I add host file entry for subdomain and access then  I am getting the following error.
java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxxxxx
        at

```
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:635)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1302)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.jsp.get_005fimage_005fpath_jsp._jspService(get_005fimage_005fpath_jsp.java:545)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel$TagWriter.endEvaluation(TagTransformModel.java:430)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel$TagWriter.afterBody(TagTransformModel.java:417)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:312)
        at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
        at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
        at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
        at com.liferay.portal.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreeMarkerTemplate.java:122)
        at com.liferay.portal.template.AbstractTemplate.processTemplate(AbstractTemplate.java:108)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doIncludeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:344)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doDispatch(ThemeUtil.java:169)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:113)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:96)
        at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:34)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dtheme_005finclude_005f1(portal_jsp.java:572)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:515)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:6556)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.sendError(PortalUtil.java:1850)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:408)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:70)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.monorail.url.filter.URLFilter.doFilter(URLFilter.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1098.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy853.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823), rather give more information on the other post that you've asked on the Liferay forums (when you don't get an answer, there's often information missing). Also, as there seems to be none of your own code involved (at least none that you post), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. While I've voted to close here, I'd like to encourage you to provide more information on your post on the Liferay forums

Comment: they are no logs in the server to add more information and issue reoccurred again after few days after server kept running for few days. in the browser, it is showing following message for one of the subdomain,

This page isn’t working 
xxx.xxxx.xxx didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: I am getting the following exception if I add host file entry and access subdomain   java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxxxxx
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)